# Identify the specifications of a relay from the writings on it

Tags: relay

I got this relay from a scrap electronic part. Please tell me how to read its specification from the writings on it.

[image]
[image]

NOTE: Its the snaps of two sides of the same relay, not the pictures of two different relays.

Comment: If you look really carefully at your camera, you can probably find a "focus" thingy on it.  Use it.  Properly.

Comment: @Olin I took it with my VGA camera phone & it dont have those luxuries. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a 12V relay (it clearly says "12V DC").

The picture on the left also says 5A @ 250V AC. That's something, but relays are quite complex and have many important parameters.
In that sense the other one is easier. It says "Takamisawa" and that's a Fujitsu brand. For the rest just make some guesses. Google for "Takamisawa 12MB". Bingo! We get hits which also say "VS", and that's also on the relay, so the type is probably "VS 12 MB". On the Fujitsu website look for power relays. We're on the right track, because there is indeed a ["VS" series](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fcai/relays/vs.pdf).

Now we have the datasheet we can find just anything we need to know. Like your question about 9V. They're 12V relays, will 9V be enough in the first place? Coil ratings are on page 3. This is a standard device (high sensitive types are "SMB" instead of "MB"). The table says that the "Must operate voltage" is 8.4V, so the 9V is sufficient, but doesn't give you much headroom. If you switch the relay with a transistor you'll have a few hundred millivolts voltage drop over the transistor and if the 9V has some tolerance too **the relay *may* not operate!** A MOSFET as switching element may be a better choice than a BJT. A low \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ type like the [NTR4170N](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NTR4170N-D.PDF) (just a random type) will have a voltage drop of just a few mV.
Coil resistance is 200\$\Omega\$, so current will be \$I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{9V}{200\Omega} = 45mA\$. Power is then only 405mW, while the rated power is 720mW, so it's clear that you're near the limits.

Bottom line: use anything printed on the relay + your imagination, and you'll often find any information you need.

---

**Q & A** (from comments)

**Q:** *What is the difference between coil's Rated power and Operate power?*
**A:** Operate Power is the power at the minimum required voltage ("Must Operate"): \$\frac{(8.4V)^2}{200Ω}\$=350mW. Rated Power is the power at the nominal voltage: \$\frac{(12V)^2}{200Ω}\$=720mW. If you can't work at the rated voltage, at least try to stay as far as possible above Must Operate Voltage; this is the *absolute minimum* for guaranteed operation.

Comment: If I want to design a transistor switch to drive it, for what collector current should I design it?

Comment: Start from the 45mA value. Most [general purpose](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC847_BC547_SER.pdf) and [small signal switching](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BSV52.pdf) transistors will have a maximum \$I_C\$ at least of 100mA, so with those you're safe. Don't forget the flyback diode over the coil.

Comment: What is the difference between coil's Rated power and Operate power?

Comment: Added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

lets see... the one on the left is  a 12 v activated relay, that should work with up to 250V AC circuit, which has a current of 5A. I believe the 80A is peak current.

The other side shows various certifications, mainly

Comment: If I provide 9V for exctation, what should be the excitation current?

Comment: @oxakhil - I go into that in my answer below (or above).

Comment: Looks like The Journeyman geek fell from his chair in the middle of that sentence...